# masonry vs jquery-masonry

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

This is my first tag request, so I'm not really sure what *should* happen here, but I think one of the following should probably be done:

- Burninate [jquery-masonry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-masonry)
- Alias [jquery-masonry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-masonry)
- Rename [masonry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/masonry) to [masonry-v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/masonry-v3)
- Change the text of one or both to help with the ambiguity

My reasons for proposing this is my confusion: I'm using jQuery with Masonry, but I'm using the newest version which has no jQuery dependency.

[jquery-masonry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-masonry)

> **Masonry is a dynamic grid layout plugin for jQuery**
>
> Masonry is a dynamic grid layout plugin for jQuery that works by
>   placing elements in optimal position based on available vertical
>   space.
>
> Think of it as the flip-side of CSS floats: whereas floating arranges
>   elements horizontally then vertically, Masonry arranges elements
>   vertically, positioning each element in the next open spot in the
>   grid.
>
> The result minimizes vertical gaps between elements of varying height,
>   just like a mason fitting stones in a wall.

[masonry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/masonry)

> **Masonry, formally jQuery Masonry, is a JavaScript cascading grid layout library.**
>
> Masonry is a JavaScript grid layout library. It works by placing
>   elements in optimal position based on available vertical space, sort
>   of like a mason fitting stones in a wall. You’ve probably seen it in
>   use all over the Internet.
>
> As of version 3, Masonry does not depend on jQuery anymore but can
>   work alongside.
>
> Created by David DeSandro, Masonry is released under the permissive
>   MIT License.

---

Extra information:

14% of questions tagged jquery-masonry are also tagged with masonry.

Looking through a few questions with the jquery-masonry tag there is really no way to tell if they are using the deprecated version with the jQuery dependency or the new version with jQuery.

Comment: I don't think that we need to do anything with  [tag:jquery-masonry], there are a lot of questions relevant to this old version of the plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think burnination is a bit extreme (that's where we mass close/delete and retag). It's obvious that [masonry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/masonry) and [jquery-masonry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-masonry) should be synonyms (the excerpts literally define them as being the same). The problem with making [masonry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/masonry) the canonical is what you said about [masonry-v3]

> I'm using JQuery with Masonry, but I'm using the newest version **which has no JQuery dependency.**

So, most of the previous questions have a jQuery dependency. Removing the jQuery part of the tag could confuse people as to which version and/or dependencies are needed. I would suggest the following

1. Make [masonry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/masonry) a synonym of [jquery-masonry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-masonry) (requires no retags)
2. Create the [masonry-v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/masonry-v3) tag and retag [jquery-masonry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-masonry) as needed. Since V3 still works with jQuery, the tags don't have to be mutually exclusive

Comment: I don't think we can say for sure "Most of the previous questions have a jQuery dependency", can we?

Comment: @RatherNotsay Possibly (I'm unfamiliar with previous versions). But your quote makes it sound like it was originally a jQuery plugin. Is that not correct?

Comment: @RatherNotsay After a bit of looking, [it was indeed a jQuery plugin at one time](https://masonry.desandro.com/v2/). So We can't just assume they're *not* using jQuery either

Comment: I assume, I just quoted the tag wiki.

Comment: Yes, I think it's clear from many of the questions that they are using JQuery, what isn't clear is whether or not they are using the version of Masonry that is JQuery *dependent*, but I take your point I suppose.

Comment: What would have helped me would be if the description of [tag:jquery-masonry] explicitly said something along the lines of "Legacy version of Masonry with JQuery dependency" (Obviously not this exactly, but something that makes it clear it's an older version)

Comment: @RatherNotsay  Regardless of what happens here, excerpts need to be edited. You can go edit those now, actually (you have that privilege).